# How to filter by a list in Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, filter, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have a model called `X`, `X` contains a field called `Ys`, a many-to-many field for a class `Y`.

If I have a list of multiple instances of the model `Y`, how to filter for `X`s that have the field `Ys` that is a superset of my list?

Example:

I have 3 `X` objects here:

`x1.Ys` = [`y1`, `y3`, `y4`]

`x2.Ys` = [`y1`, `y2`, `y3`]

`x3.Ys` = [`y1`, `y2`]

items_list: [`y1`, `y2`]

I want to write `X.objects.filter(xxx=items_list)` and get `x2`, and `x3` but not `x1`.

What should I write in place of `xxx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in).

For example.

```
X.objects.filter(Ys__in=items_list)
```

EDIT: You can try this using [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
from django.db.models import Count

list_count = len(items_list)
X.objects.filter(YS__in=items_list).annotate(count_ys=Count('Ys')).filter(count_ys=list_count)
```

Comment: This will return `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`. I want to get items that contain both `y1` and `y2`. `x1` will be returned because it contains `y1` even though it doesn't contain `y2`.

Comment: Is there a way to write it in the form `Q(xxx)` ?

Comment: @StackExchange123 I think it's better this way with annotation. You need to compare with every *value* in the list with *Ys* using Q

Answer (score 1):

Use `union` and `difference` on the 2 set and that will work for you :

```py
x1.Ys = set([y1, y3, y4])
x2.Ys = set([y1, y2, y3])
x3.Ys = set([y1, y2])

items_list = set.union(x2.Ys, x3.Ys).difference(x1.Ys)
```

This will merge `x2` and `x3` and remove all element from `x1`

And now easy query :

```py
X.objects.filter(Ys__in=items_list)
```